# Android get selected item position from Class structure in AutoComplete

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to find Class structure position as an ArrayList from AutoComplete, for example I have this class structure:

```
public class Clients {

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    public int id;

    @DatabaseField
    public int client_code;

    public int getClient_code() {
        return client_code;
    }
}
```

And I define `ArrayList` from this class as:

```
private ArrayList<Clients> customersList = new ArrayList<Clients>();
```

Now I have some data into this arrayList and I want to get selected position to find which `client_code` is selected.

```
at_sender_package.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long rowId) {
        int selectedposition=position;
        Log.e("SELECTED ITEM: ", customersList.get(selectedposition).getClient_code()+"");
    }
});
```

Unfortunately I get this error:

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
>        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
>                   at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)

**my array list dont empty and i have 3 item into that and i dont have any problem to get selected text, i want to only get selected position not selected text**

for example :

```
Log.e("POS: ", parent.getItemAtPosition(position) + "");
```

Result is: `POS: Item 1)`

Comment: yes right only. nothing in list, then how it will show??

Comment: @Shadow post updated, please review that sir,

Comment: where you are inserting datas?

Comment: @Shadow in bakcground and `customersList.size();` is 3

Comment: try to log the size in setOnItemClickListener .What does it return?

Comment: @Payal size is 3 and after click on Auto complete that show popup of some data and i can selected item text, but i want to get selected position

Answer (score 0):

Here your list is empty and you are trying to get data from it.

The proactive way to escape this error is to apply one check of list's length before using its elements.

like :

```
if(customersList.size() > 0) {
//do your stuff

}
```

You can read more about this error here :

http://voidexception.weebly.com/array-index-out-of-bounds-exception.html

Comment: my array list dont empty and i have 3 item into that and i dont have any problem to get selected text, i want to only get selected position not selected text sir,

Comment: See the error message you have posted, it is saying `Invalid index 0, size is 0`. size of arraylist is 0 please go through the code once more you are using an empty list

Comment: yes sir. i get this error when i try to get position

Comment: i'm sorry sir. my widget is `AutoComplete` i'm forget to say it

Comment: use logging statement in `onItemClick` method

Comment: i want to only get selected position,nothing

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

means your arraylist, `customersList` is empty and you want to get item at position 0 which is invalid.Therefore first check `customersList` length as

```
if (customersList.size() > 0) {
    Log.e("SELECTED ITEM: ", customersList.get(selectedposition).getClient_code() + "");
} else {
    Log.e("SELECTED ITEM: ", "customersList is empty");
}
```